# Determine different cells for iPhone and iPad in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview, detection

I just try to create an app for iPhone and iPad. For this i created a tableview that creates cells expecting the json that will be received when the app is loading. Inside the method

```
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:
```

I initiate the cell that will be used for the iPhone and I set the specific values from the json. The cell I use is a custom Cell i created with a new object and NIB-File. The code looks like this:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"tvChannelIdentifier";

tvChannelCell *cell = (tvChannelCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"tvChannelCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
....
```

Now that I try to make the app work on the iPad too, I created a new custom cell, also with a new object and a NIB-File. The names of the variables are the same as in the customIPhoneCell so that I don't have to change the whole code. I just inserted a switch inside the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: so that i show the right cell but it can't be accessed by the code:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"tvChannelCell";
static NSString *IPadCellIdentifier = @"tvChannelIPadCell";


//determination which device ---> choose cell
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
    tvChannelCell *cell = (tvChannelCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

}else{

    tvChannelIPadCell = (tvChannelIPadCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:IPadCellIdentifier];
}
```

I tried to define the cell objects at the top of the class but then i can't use the same variable name. I also tried to choose the NIB file of the iPad to check if it'll be displayed but nothing happens. And I tried to set an UITableviewcell at the top,

```
UITableViewCell *cell
```

and set the specific cell type inside my switch in cellForRowAtIndexPath but then the variables can't be accessed.

So my question is, is it possible to do this switch inside the tableview method or do i have to code to several parts for each device where each celltype has its own variablename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I do:

I create **only one UITableViewCell subclass with 2 xibs**, one xib for iPad and another for iPhone.

```
tvChannelCell *cell = (tvChannelCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
NSArray *nib;
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){

     nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"tvChannelCell_iPhone" owner:self options:nil];

}else{

    nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"tvChannelCell_iPad" owner:self options:nil];
}

    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: thank you. i now connected the iPad-NIB to the same object as the iPhone-NIB.

Comment: @xandruCea : Its good your issue is solved, but you should always consider or accept answers (if they are same), the answer which was answered first..

Comment: @jcesar : your right, but your answer had the init of the cell object in the first line, which just helped me to connect both NIB-files with just one object, so yours' helped me most

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple, why don't you create another nib for iPad, and just access it when device is iPad.

You all code will remain same, i.e. you don't need to compare iPad like anywhere

Like:

```
if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib;
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone){
     nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"tvChannelCell-iPad" owner:self options:nil];}
    else{
    nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"tvChannelCell" owner:self options:nil];}
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this line of code useful for differenciating iphone and ipad,

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        tvChannelCell *cell = (tvChannelCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }else{

        cell = (tvChannelIPadCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:IPadCellIdentifier];

     }
```